# applications of log-concave and log-convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm so excited about log-concave and log-convex functions!

I found a number of good properties of these functions, such as the following:

```
1- The Laplace transform of a non-negative function is log-convex.
2- The convolution of two log-concave functions is log-concave.
3- The product of log-concave functions is log-concave.
```

But I can't find any information about the usefulness of these for any applications.

Thanks in advance.